# Why does \DTLgetkeyforcolumn not work?

Tags: external-files, datatool

I'm currently learning how to use the `datatool` package. I have a lot of `.txt`-files that need to be processed automatically. But if `datatool` loads a wrong kind of `.txt`-file I need to be able to check it. The way I want to do it is to check the key's of the columns, but the command `\DTLgetkeyforcolumn` returns the error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \db@row@id@w

l.58 \DTLgetkeyforcolumn{\colkey}{data}{1}
```

I have absolutely no clue what that means... The source code can be found in the [`datatool` manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool).
Search for the function and you will get to it. I really don't understand it, and can't see anywhere `\db@row@id@w`. Could it be a bug in the package? Trying to redefine the function only results in errors.

Edit:
**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloadrawdb{data}{data.txt} %load data.txt, store in database data

\begin{document}
  % Display the table, bold are the headers
  \DTLdisplaydb{data}

  % Search for header ColTwo and store index into \colindex
  \DTLgetcolumnindex{\colindex}{data}{ColTwo}
  \colindex % returns 2

  % Search the index and store the header into \colkey
  \DTLgetkeyforcolumn{\colkey}{data}{\colindex} % Error
  \colkey

\end{document}
```

**data.txt**

```
ColOne,ColTwo,ColThree
a,b,2
c,d,5
```

Gives no output at all.

Comment: Could you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem? It helps us to track the error down. `:)`

Comment: Added, but it doesn't work mind you `;)`

Comment: Seems like a bug. Maybe you should contact the package maintainer.

Comment: I've sent a mail to him, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sent a mail to the package maintainer (Nicola Talbot) who gave me a temporary workaround. Paste the following under `\usepackage{datatool}`. This bug will be fixed in a future patch.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@dtl@getkeyforcolumn}[3]{%
 \def\@dtl@get@keyforcolumn##1% before stuff
   \db@plist@elt@w% start of block
   \db@col@id@w #3\db@col@id@end@% index
   \db@key@id@w ##2\db@key@id@end@% key
   \db@type@id@w ##3\db@type@id@end@% data type
   \db@header@id@w ##4\db@header@id@end@% header
   \db@col@id@w #3\db@col@id@end@% index
   \db@plist@elt@end@% end of block
   ##5\q@nil{\def#1{##2}}%
 \edef\@dtl@tmp{\expandafter\the\csname dtlkeys@#2\endcsname}%
 \expandafter\@dtl@get@keyforcolumn\@dtl@tmp
   \db@plist@elt@w% start of block
   \db@col@id@w #3\db@col@id@end@ %index
   \db@key@id@w \@nil\db@key@id@end@% key
   \db@type@id@w \db@type@id@end@% data type
   \db@header@id@w \db@header@id@end@% header
   \db@col@id@w #3\db@col@id@end@% index
   \db@plist@elt@end@% end of block
   \q@nil
}
\makeatother
```